# Get last message form chat system

Tags: jquery, mysql, chat, message

My problem is that I'm trying to create a chat messaging system,

This is what I have so far.

```
Chat
chat_id | member_id | added

Member to Chat
member_to_chat_id | member_id | chat_id

Chat Message
chat_message_id | member_to_chat_id | message | added
```

So I want to get all chats where member is involved. I'm doing it this way

```
Select c.chat_id 
From member_to_chat m2c 
Left Join chat c ON c.chat_id = m2c.chat_id WHERE m2c.member_id = 1 
GROUP by c.chat_id
```

Fiddle is here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d1ab/1

Is there a way to get the last message in this group chat and form who member is it?

The expected result should look something like this

if user Alex is in two chats, and he wrote the last message

```
chat_id | member_name | member_message
1         Alex          Test1
2         Alex          Test2
```

Later on if someone else add a message in chat with id 1 we still get all chats by user id 1:Alex but the message should be from another member so somthing like this:

```
chat_id | member_name | member_message
1         John          Last Test1
2         Alex          Test2
```

Hope this make sense now.

Comment: For clarity, can you provide the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the result has to be like this
chat_id | The member who last write to this chat | the last message in this chat,

1 | Alex  | 1 | Test message 1

2 | John | 2 | Test message 2

3 | Alex  | 1 | 123
I don't  know if the schema is ok, I just invented it, I think that I can add another key in  chat_message -> chat_id so I can have the chat id there and after this with one left join to get it, but I was wondering if there is a way to get it wihout to add another key thanks in advance and sorry if my English is not so good.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm too confused by your schema to provide an answer but suffice to say that there is no problem in SQL for which the accepted answer is appropriate.

Comment: Hi @Alex there is some improvement in my answer, I find better solution for your problem than the first one I offered to you :) So i think you should check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i hope this is the last edit i'm gonna make here is how you can do what you want i didn't understand completely your problem at first but with your last edit i thing this is solution:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT m2c.chat_id, m.name, cm.message
    FROM member_to_chat m2c
    INNER JOIN chat_message cm
    ON m2c.member_to_chat_id = cm.member_to_chat_id
    INNER JOIN members m
    ON m2c.member_id = m.member_id
    WHERE m2c.chat_id IN (SELECT c.chat_id
                          FROM member_to_chat m2c 
                          INNER JOIN chat c ON c.chat_id = m2c.chat_id 
                          WHERE m2c.member_id = 2)
    ORDER BY cm.chat_message_id DESC) resultTable
GROUP BY chat_id
```

Here is Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7443/9/0 to test it (it's your fiddle just little edited to test query) GL

**EDIT:**

Hi again I had to improve my answer again. Thanks to tips and advice that **Strawberry** make I find better solution for this problem... (You can see our little discussion in comments below this answer)...

Here is a link of manual where everything starts https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

First here is a code for correlated subquery:

```
SELECT m2c.chat_id, m.name, cm.message
FROM member_to_chat m2c
INNER JOIN chat_message cm
ON m2c.member_to_chat_id = cm.member_to_chat_id
INNER JOIN members m
ON m2c.member_id = m.member_id
WHERE m2c.chat_id IN (SELECT c.chat_id
                      FROM member_to_chat m2c 
                      INNER JOIN chat c ON c.chat_id = m2c.chat_id 
                      WHERE m2c.member_id = 2)
AND cm.chat_message_id = (SELECT MAX(cmm.chat_message_id)
                          FROM chat_message cmm
                          INNER JOIN member_to_chat m2cm
                          on m2cm.member_to_chat_id = cmm.member_to_chat_id
                          WHERE m2c.chat_id = m2cm.chat_id)
```

End here is SQL Fiddle for that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7443/17/0

And here is a code for second solution based on JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.chat_id, name, message FROM (
SELECT m2c.chat_id, m.name, cm.message, cm.chat_message_id
FROM member_to_chat m2c
INNER JOIN chat_message cm
ON m2c.member_to_chat_id = cm.member_to_chat_id
INNER JOIN members m
ON m2c.member_id = m.member_id
WHERE m2c.chat_id IN (SELECT c.chat_id
                      FROM member_to_chat m2c 
                      INNER JOIN chat c ON c.chat_id = m2c.chat_id 
                      WHERE m2c.member_id = 2)) AS t1                 
JOIN (SELECT m2c.chat_id, MAX(cm.chat_message_id) as maxChatId
      FROM chat_message cm
      INNER JOIN member_to_chat m2c
      ON m2c.member_to_chat_id = cm.member_to_chat_id
      GROUP BY chat_id) AS t2 
ON t1.chat_id = t2.chat_id 
AND t1.chat_message_id = t2.maxChatId
```

And here is a Fiddle for that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7443/43/0

Again big credits for this improvement on this answer goes to **Strawberry** who show me a better way to solve problem like this. Thanks again!

P.S. Sorry I for late update I have some other thinks to do, but better ever than never. :) GL

Comment: 9 times out of 10, if you find yourself with a GROUP BY clause and no aggregating functions, you can bet that something has gone very, very wrong.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for advice i'll remember that, but i just try to help and this is first idea how i could get desired results for this problem... I would like to try solve it on different (better) way... Any suggestion where i should start?

Comment: The manual would be a good place to start. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @Strawberry is something like this more acceptable http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7443/17/0   :)

Comment: I thought that this is correlated subquery. I have m2c.chat_id in subquery which is a reference to member_to_chat table in outer query

Comment: @Strawberry I thing i finally solve it :) here it is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7443/43/0 Somehow i miss to type ON part in last Inner join so i had little problem to find why won't work as expected (stupid mistake). That manual is very good, right place to start. Thank you for all tips. If you have free time check my last solution and if is good i can add it to my answer and message to Alex that there is a better solution for his problem :) Thanks again any way